# how to pass variable from jquery ajax to php mvc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the [php-mvc](https://github.com/panique/mini) and adding search functionality using ajax. How am going to pass the value from the `input` to model and query the value. I tried to add `$_GET['searchData']` inside `getAllUsersProfiles` method but it doesn't get the value.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchData" placeholder="search name here..." />
...
<!--where I want to output the search result -->      
<tbody id="account_results"></tbody>
```

JS:

```
$("#searchData").keyup(function(){

  var searchValue = $.trim($(this).val());

  if(searchValue !== ''){

        $.get("<?php echo URL; ?>admin/index/", function(returnData){

          if(!returnData)
            $("#account_results").html("<p>No record(s) found.</p>");
          else
            $("#account_results").html(returnData);
        });
  }

});
```

PHP Model:

```
public function getAllUsersProfiles()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, email, active, firstname, lastname
            FROM users";

    if(isset($_GET['searchData'])) {
        $sql .= " WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(firstname), ' ', TRIM(lastname))
                        LIKE '%:searchData%'";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    }
    else
      //if search input is not set, output all of the list.
      $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);

      $sth->execute();
      $all_users_profiles = array();
      foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $user) {
        //code here..
      }
     return $users;
}
```

PHP Controller:

```
class Admin extends Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $admin_model = $this->loadModel('Admin');
    $this->view->users = $admin_model->getAllUsersProfiles();
    $this->view->render('admin/index');
}
```

Comment: You should probably narrow down the code to the relevant sections.  This is a lot of code and most will not read that far.

Comment: @rfornal ok, let me edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code doesn't get the searchData value because you don't send it with the GET request. Try this in your JS part:

```
$("#searchData").keyup(function(){
  var searchValue = $.trim($(this).val()), url = '<?php echo URL; ?>/admin/index/?searchData=' + searchValue;

  if(searchValue !== ''){
        $.get(url, function(returnData){

          if(!returnData)
            $("#account_results").html("<p>No record(s) found.</p>");
          else
            $("#account_results").html(returnData);
        });
  }
});
```

And then you can get the value with `$_GET['searchData']` in PHP

Comment: this works, however there is a problem rendering in the controller. so for know I didn't bother figure it out. I use an alternative solution instead of using an ajax. I really need to finish this. thanks though :)

Comment: So what's the rendering problem?

Comment: `$this->view->render('admin/index');` this one, whenever I input a value, the out put is the whole page inside the table.

Comment: Maybe you can leave that render call out, and just print the result of the `getAllUsersProfiles()` method as a JSON string?

Comment: I was thinking about json, but not very familiar using json in php. I don't have much time to research and study. :) but when I finish this thing that I'm working on, I'll give it some time to learn.

Comment: hmm. if I also call out the render, the page where I want to the result to appear won't be loaded.

Comment: That's weird, it should always work when you just `print(json_encode(array(...)));`. Maybe add an `exit();` after that?